# unable to build a custom Hyperledger Fabric network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am trying to build own network using fabric sample's first network components. Literally just renamed the organization names and trying to connect. But I am getting the following error.

```
./byfn.sh up -c "trustrace"
Starting for channel 'trustrace' with CLI timeout of '10' seconds and CLI delay of '3' seconds
Continue? [Y/n] Y
proceeding ...
LOCAL_VERSION=1.3.0
DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=1.3.0
Starting peer1.supplier.company.org ...
peer1.brand.company.org is up-to-date
Starting peer1.supplier.company.org
peer0.brand.company.org is up-to-date
Starting peer0.supplier.company.org ...
Starting orderer.company.org ...
Starting peer0.supplier.company.org
Starting peer0.supplier.company.org ... done
cli is up-to-date

 ____    _____      _      ____    _____
/ ___|  |_   _|    / \    |  _ \  |_   _|
\___ \    | |     / _ \   | |_) |   | |
 ___) |   | |    / ___ \  |  _ <    | |
|____/    |_|   /_/   \_\ |_| \_\   |_|

Build your first network (BYFN) end-to-end test

Channel name : trustrace
Creating channel...
+ peer channel create -o orderer.company.org:7050 -c trustrace -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls true --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/company.org/orderers/orderer.company.org/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.company.org-cert.pem
+ res=1
+ set +x
Error: failed to create deliver client: orderer client failed to connect to orderer.company.org:7050: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Channel creation failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========= ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ===========

ERROR !!!! Test failed
```

**EDIT**

I have already the company.org in my host file, that is being translated into localhost - 127.0.0.1 and the debug logs goes here:

```
2018-11-28 07:28:13.588 UTC [msp] setupSigningIdentity -> DEBU 035 Signing identity expires at 2028-11-25 07:23:00 +0000 UTC
2018-11-28 07:28:13.588 UTC [msp] Validate -> DEBU 036 MSP BrandMSP validating identity
2018-11-28 07:28:13.589 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 037 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-11-28 07:28:13.589 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 038 parsed scheme: ""
2018-11-28 07:28:13.589 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 039 scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2018-11-28 07:28:13.589 UTC [grpc] watcher -> DEBU 03a ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{orderer.company.org:7050 0  <nil>}]
2018-11-28 07:28:13.589 UTC [grpc] switchBalancer -> DEBU 03b ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2018-11-28 07:28:13.590 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 03c pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420247a80, CONNECTING
2018-11-28 07:28:13.591 UTC [grpc] createTransport -> DEBU 03d grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {orderer.company.org:7050 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: lookup orderer.company.org on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host". Reconnecting...
2018-11-28 07:28:13.591 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 03e pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420247a80, TRANSIENT_FAILURE
2018-11-28 07:28:14.590 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 03f pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420247a80, CONNECTING
2018-11-28 07:28:14.593 UTC [grpc] createTransport -> DEBU 040 grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {orderer.company.org:7050 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: lookup orderer.company.org on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host". Reconnecting...
2018-11-28 07:28:14.593 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 041 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420247a80, TRANSIENT_FAILURE
2018-11-28 07:28:16.115 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 042 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420247a80, CONNECTING
2018-11-28 07:28:16.121 UTC [grpc] createTransport -> DEBU 043 grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {orderer.company.org:7050 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: lookup orderer.company.org on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host". Reconnecting...
2018-11-28 07:28:16.121 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 044 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420247a80, TRANSIENT_FAILURE
Error: failed to create deliver client: orderer client failed to connect to orderer.company.org:7050: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Channel creation failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========= ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ===========

ERROR !!!! Test failed
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because the previous volume interfering with the current one. Try removing all volumes before restarting the network.

```
docker stop $(docker ps -aq)

docker rm $(docker ps -aq)

docker volume prune
```

First 2 commands removes all running containers. (Check this if you want to remove all), last commands removes all previous volumes.